# Type error: unsupported operand

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that takes in a number and returns the sum of the digits raised to the power of its corresponding position.
Example: >>>534 returns 5^1 + 3^2 + 4^3.

> > > > 7

My code works for range of numbers below 100. It fails for 3-digit numbers with the error message: TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

My code bellow. I apologize in advance for poorly structured code. I'm just a beginner. Thank you.

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b):
    dict1 = {}
    for k in range(a,b+1):
        if k < 10:
            dict1[k] = k**1

        else:
            num_len = int(len(str(k))) + 1

            def dig_pow(k):
                nonlocal num_len
                num_len -= 1
                if k < 10:
                    return k
                else:
                    var = (k%10)**num_len + dig_pow(k//10)
                    dict1[k] = var

            dig_pow(k)
    return dict1
print(sum_dig_pow(98, 100))
```

Comment: `dig_pow` doesn't explicitly return anything in the `else` case, meaning the return defaults to None. What are you wanting to be returned there?

Comment: `5 + 9 + 64` equals `78`, not `7`

Comment: @Carcigenicate, i wanted the dig_pow function to append its result to the dictionary(dict1)...the program works for single and double digits, but fails for anything above. I think the problem is with the recursive call.

Comment: Again, you don't return anything in the else case: `... else: var = (k%10)**num_len + dig_pow(k//10); dict1[k] = var`. There's no `return` there. Every path needs to end in a return. If you want to use recursion, you can't mix that with appending to mutable objects and relying on a return value only part of the time. You either use all mutation, or you use the return value.

Comment: ok, is there a way out? How do I return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's minutely less efficent, but I think that treating your input number as a string, then iterating through it is simpler to understand then seperating the digits mathematically.

```
def dig_pow(n):
    return sum(int(digit)**position for position, digit in enumerate(str(n), start=1))

dig_pow(534)
# 78
```

Comment: This is smart solution, but can you help point out why my program fail on numbers above 2-digits

Comment: @Tpenny When you run `dig_pow(100)`, that does `0+dig_pow(10)` at some point.  Since `dig_pow(10)` doesn't return anything, it implicitly returns `None`.  You then try to do `0+None`, which is  a `TypeError`.  Just do `return var` after `dict1[k] = var`